# node.js : reading lines from csv into an array

Tags: node.js, csv, stream, lazy-sequences

I want to read some lines from a large csv file. A quick search here on SO pointed me to the 'lazy' module. Here's my attempt:

```
items = []
stream = fs.createReadStream src
lazy(stream)
    .lines
    .skip(1)
    .take(5)
    .forEach((line)->
        items.push line.toString())
    .on('end', ->
        console.log items)
```

But it doesn't print anything. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The `'end'` event doesn't appear to be emitted down the chain. Only [`'data'` and `'pipe'` are](https://github.com/pkrumins/node-lazy/blob/master/lazy.js#L72-L79).

Based on [the definition of `.join()`](https://github.com/pkrumins/node-lazy/blob/master/lazy.js#L168-L176), `'pipe'` seems to be what `lazy` uses.

```
# ...
    .forEach((line)->
        items.push line.toString())
    .on('pipe', () ->
        console.log items)
```

You could also just use `.join()` to stay with `lazy`'s own API:

```
# ...
    .forEach((line)->
        items.push line.toString())
    .join(() ->
        console.log items)
```

---

Side note: you don't necessarily need to collect the `items` yourself. You can also use `.map()`:

```
lazy(stream)
    .lines
    .skip(1)
    .take(5)
    .map(item -> item.toString())
    .join((items) -> console.log items)
```

Or possibly with just:

```
# ...
    .map(String)
    .join(console.log);
```